# Terminating infinite-loop script embedded in tmux status bar

Tags: shell-script, tmux, subshell

I have an infinite `while` loop bash script embedded in tmux status bar. In ~/.tmux/conf:

```
set -g status-right '... #(path/loop.sh) ...'
```

Tmux seems to run this script with `sh -c`. After tmux started:

```
$ ps x | grep loop.sh
23433 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto loop.sh
31814 ?        S      0:00 sh -c path/loop.sh
31818 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash path/loop.sh
```

`tmux kill-session` terminates the `sh -c` process. If I `strace` it and kill the session:

```
$ strace -p 31814
strace: Process 31814 attached
wait4(-1, 0x7ffeacbfbf9c, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=27643, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGTERM +++
```

But the subshell is left untouched because of the infinite loop:

```
$ ps x | grep loop.sh
 2443 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto loop.sh
31818 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash path/loop.sh
```

**Question**

I want the subshell to be terminated automatically after the tmux session ends. Is there a way to do this, by changing tmux settings or handling `SIGTERM` sent to the `sh -c` process?

(**Edit**: tmux version is 2.8)

Comment: This may have been fixed in tmux 2.7 or earlier, as a quick test showed my background script getting sighup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, child processes started with `tmux -c "start process here"` seem to survive the corresponding `tmux` sessions. I have pored over `tmux`' extensive  man page and for a while I hoped that setting up a `tmux` command's after-hook globally could help. After-hooks have the following form:

```
 $ tmux set-hook -g after-session-closed your_cmd_here
```

where *"your_cmd_here"* could have been used to kill the child process generating your infinite loop. But it does not help that way, because *"your_cmd_here"* must in fact be a `tmux` cmd not a linux shell cmd.

Instead a quick hack would be to add a line inside the infinite loop of your  `/path/loop.sh` script, such as:

```
 [ "x$(ps -e | grep tmux | grep -v grep)" = "x" ] && break
```

This will break you out of the infinite loop as soon as `tmux` does not show any active process in output of `ps -ae`.  On the contrary, if a `tmux` related process shows then the loop continues unaffected.

Actually a better version of the above test, for the corner case where you would quit your `tmux` session(s), but sill have e.g. a `man tmux` process active on your system, is:

```
 [ $(\ps -e |  awk 'BEGIN {rv=0}; tolower($0) ~/tmux/ {if ($4 == "tmux") {rv=1}; exit} END {print rv}') == "1" ] && break
```

- The above deals with cases when `tmux` appears in the output of `\ps -e` but not as the main process, i.e. not in position 4 on the output line of `ps -e`, but as an argument to a running process, or casually as a (sub-)string embedded in the output of `\ps -e`.
- Note how I used the unadulterated form of `ps` by adding a backslash before the cmd as `\ps`. This is to prevent modified versions of the cmd to mess with positional parameter numbering in `awk`.  E.g. if you used  `\ps -eF` instead of `\ps -e` for instance, you would need to change `$4` to `$11`.

HTH.